# Hyperledger composer tutorial error 500 on deploying trade-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been following these tutorials. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org. At step eleven, it ask me to deploy a trade-network to get the .bna file. When I go to https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/login, choose trade-network, then press on deploy a trade-network, it gives error such as this `{"status":500,"name":"web_sql_went_bad","message":"unknown","reason":"The quota has been exceeded."}`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by closing opened hyperledger network from console, cleaning cookies, then reopen it on safari.